# How to retrieve saved password from cyberduck in windows

Tags: windows-7, linux, passwords, cyberduck

I forgot my admin password for my netgear readynas and did not setup password recovery when I installed. We have a whole lots of data in the server and I am a bit scare to do the hard reset. I have saved the password in Cyberduck in one of the computer in the network, so I can login with the root password using cyberduck. So, I think it is best if I can retrieve the password from CyberDuck, unfortunately, I don't know how.

If anyone know, please, kindly help.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

#### I think it is best if I can retrieve the password from CyberDuck

You can use SmartFTP:

> We discovered that SmartFTP, a shareware FTP client comes with an
> independent password recovery tool supporting 14 different types of
> FTP client software which are Core FTP, CuteFTP, **Cyberduck**, FFFTP,
> FileZilla, FireFTP, FlashFXP, FTPRush, FTP Voyager, FTP EXpert, PuTTY,
> Total Commander, WinSCP and WS_FTP. Unlike SmartFTP, the password
> recovery tool is actually free and portable which can be found in the
> program’s directory as the filename PasswordRecovery.exe after
> installation.
>
> Do take note that although the SmartFTP password recovery tool is
> portable, it has some dependencies like msvcp140.dll,
> vcruntime140.dll, mfc140u.dll, etc. You can use third party tools such
> as Dependency Walker to scan for the required files and make sure that
> they are stored at the same location as the password recovery tool.
>
> [Download SmartFTP](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/download/did/3454/)

Source [3 Methods to Recover FTP Password Saved in FTP Client Software](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/ftp-passwords-saved-in-ftp-client-software-are-unsafe/)

The password recovery option is now built into SmartFTP. See below.

---

#### Password Recovery

> SmartFTP can import FTP sites including the password from various
> other applications.
>
> You can [import all the sites/passwords into SmartFTP](https://www.smartftp.com/support/kb/37).
>
> Supported applications:
>
> - Core FTP Lite
> - Core FTP Pro
> - CuteFTP Home
> - CuteFTP Professional
> - Cyberduck
> - FFFTP
> - FileZilla
> - FireFTP
> - FlashFXP
> - FTP Rush
> - FTP Voyager
> - FTP Expert
> - PuTTY
> - Total Commander (former Windows Commander)
> - WinSCP
> - WS_FTP Home
> - WS_FTP Professional

Source [Password Recovery](https://www.smartftp.com/password)

Comment: I have installed SmartFTP, but could not find the file PasswordRecovery.exe. Any suggestion? Please help.

Comment: @Ben2014 The password recovery option is now built into SmartFTP. See updated answer..